# getOrgChart undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, orgchart

My need is to display OrgChart vertically and found `getOrgChart` is the one to try. I downloaded the js file from [here](http://www.getorgchart.com/Download) and followed the instructions but I am getting `getOrgChart is not defined`. I did `alert(jQuery)` to check whether the jquery is loaded and everything working fine. I tried the sample demo ones which came with the free download package and those are also getting same issues `$(...).getOrgChart is not a function`. Please let me know what could be the issue? Do I need to purchase the full version to get it worked? I wanted to test the free version first and then buy the license one.

Comment: There are code issues in the given free package version we need to fix them to get the sample files worked ... I request the team to look on to the free version package. I would like to know the difference between free and licensed version... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to include the javascript source in your HTML?

```
<script src="../getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<link href="../getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling any javascript function it needs the related javascript library files should be declared before. So please check it before the calling that library files are added.